# Missing Fields in Freeform v4.2.3

Tags: solspace-freeform, fields

Some of my primary fields that are used on multiple forms (like First Name, Last Name, Email) are now missing from the list of available fields. If I try to recreate the field, it says a field with that name already exists. On the forms that use those fields, the space where they should be is blank. Is there a limit to the # of fields, and did these early-created fields get dumped as I added more and more over the years? Any way to repair these missing fields?

Comment: EE version? And could you give us a count of the number of fields on that form? The theoretical limit is dependant on your server, PHP environment variables, and MySQL setup. Have you upgraded anything recently? Has your hosting partner done any automated environment upgrades?

Comment: And also, **please** post an example of your form template that is failing!

Answer (score 0):

EE v2.10.1. 
13 fields on the particular form, but the same fields are missing on other forms as well. I reuse the standard fields (First Name, Last Name, Email, etc on lots of forms). 
Using MSM with several sites, 3 of which have FreeForm forms. Is there a limit to the total # of fields for the entire installation? I do have lots of fields in the system for our various forms, and don't necessarily get rid of old fields that are no longer in use.

Live page with form showing missing fields (http://sdyc.org/race/forms/odw_reg). Should have First Name, Last Name, Boat Name, Email, Phone, and an Agree button at the bottom.

I also notice that the fields are showing up correctly on the main site, just not the MSM sites...

Attached a picture of the template page. Not sure how to grab the template code itself.

[image]

Comment: Please take the content from this **non**-answer, and edit your original question. Then please delete this answer. Thank you.